# .net ajaxtoolkit conflicting with existing jquery ajax function

Tags: jquery, .net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I hope someone can lend me a hand with a problem i am having. I have a page that's using a jquery modal window as a login control. Part of the js code that handles the ajax login submit looks ike this:

```
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/ajax/loginhandler.aspx',
            data: 'e=' + encodeURIComponent(e) + '&p=' + encodeURIComponent(p),
            success: function (msg) {
                // the ajax page will always send a success response, so the error and success actions are here
                if (msg) { //error
                    //var msgs = msg.replace("\n", "</div><div class='errMsg'>");
                    $("#errors").html("<div class='errMsg'>" + msg + "</div>");
                    $("#login_popup .errMsg").show();
                }
```

It's the last two lines of code that i think are failing, since that should show the error message. This was working, until i added the ajax toolkit to the site, then it stopped. So i assume there's some sort of conflict there. Does anyone know how i can work around this? Just to be clear - when they click ont he submit button, the loginhandler.aspx page does recieve their submitted info and works as intended. It does give back the correct error message.

I'd rather get this working otherwise i basically have to throw out a days worth of work and get rid of some .net ajax controls i added to the site.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide JS console error message?

Comment: this might be helpful http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: how would i go about providing the error? So far i haven't seen any errors come up, either in page, or using firebug, but maybe i was doing something wrong.

Comment: rupesh - i'm not sure where i would use .noConflict. It sounds like using this gives up some control form jquery to the other javascript functions, but i want to do the opposite. I want to make sure jquery maintains control. I want to make sure my above code sample runs, and that the .Net ajaxtoolkit can't interfere with that code.

Comment: if this helps in any way - after the last line of code i pasted above, if i put in alert(msg); - that works. I get a popup window with the text from msg in it.